# Disable referential integrity in .NET typed dataset?

Tags: .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a large typed dataset which I want to partially fill for unit testing, however the dataset has sprawling referential integrity, meaning I can't just populate the small areas of data relevant to the test.

Unless there is some way to switch of referential integrity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can disable referential integrity in typed datasets.

Set the property `[EnforceConstraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.enforceconstraints.aspx)' to false.

Answer (score 1):

If there were some way to "switch it off", then it wouldn't be referential integrity, would it?

Flippancy aside, a unit test is supposed to test a single, isolated, piece of functionality. If your test cannot handle the expected return data, then it is not a unit test and you should fix the test. If your dataset contains multiple pieces of functionality that are not relevant to each other, then the dataset should be broken into smaller separate units

Comment: Dour my friend, this answer is twaddle. How does injecting a mocked dataset into a test differ in any way from injecting a mocked collection or list or any other datasource? The dataset doesn't represent functionality any more than a collection does. As it happens I have no choice about using datasets - it's legacy code - believe me I'd rather not! And by the way, there is a way to disable referential integrity.. see my own answer :)